# Open Access to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a possible way to open a Google analytics account to be seen for everyone? of course only for viewing reports not for edit goals and other stuff.

I haver seen the option to give access to certain users, I would like to have something like this but for any user on the web.

Comment: There is a 3rd party site that allows you to do this: http://www.seethestats.com/

Comment: Another 3rd party solution:
[EmbeddedAnalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Google Analytics doesn't allow this. That's why many people who need public display of statistics (such as for advertisers) **use [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/)** - it's very similar to Google Analytics but completely public.

Comment: I'll give a check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a web server, you can run [Piwik](http://www.amahi.org/apps/piwik).

Also, if you want to use it in a server and install it easily (literally one-click), you can use something like Amahi (link included above - since I am limited to one link), which is meant for home/small business or VPS server deployment.

Disclaimer: I am a fan of Piwik and I packaged it for one-click install for Amahi. I started Amahi, which has one of the largest (if not the largest) web app "app store" for easy deployment.